# Permissions to see and script objects, but not alter them?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, ddl

I am a software developer.

I have a production database that I need full ddl read access to, but not any ddl write or execute access.

Is there a script I can send my DBA that will grant me full ddl read access without allowing me to affect the database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need `VIEW DEFINITION` on the database and that will give you access to the DDL.

```
USE <database>;
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO <user>;
```

Comment: Hi. A bit late to the party, but is there an easy way to view who have gotten this permission set?